# android image changed with button click in sequence

Tags: android

I would like to make a simple app with an image, and two buttons under it. A next button, and a previous button. When they click "next" it will change the picture to the next picture. When they click "previous", it will change the picture to the previous picture. My activity name is "imagescreen" and my button ID's are "previous" and "next". My imageview ID is "ImageView".

I can't seem to make this work. I have tried this, but my app is crashing. Sorry I am new to this and trying my best.

I would also like to make it for the "previous" button is grayed out/disabled when on the first image (which is resource r1.png) but can't figure out how to do that.

```
public class imagescreen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagescreen);

    previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
    previous.setOnClickListener(this);

    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.swipepage, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.next:
            if (a == 0) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r2);
                a = 1;
            } else if (a == 1) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r3);
                a = 2;
            } else if (a == 2) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r1);
                a = 3;
        case R.id.previous:
            a--;
            View previous;
            previous.performClick();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your log which you are getting on crash.

Comment: Add 'break' statement after R.id.next case.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do like this. Use Viewpager for image change it support swipe to next and previous.

Also you can write code for buttons also.

see this Tutorial will helpful. [Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is crashing with NPE, seeing I don't see where you have declared what "a" is, and you have not declared your "image" imageView.

You could do something like this:

```
     public class ImageScreen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button previous, next;
ImageView image;
int a;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagescreen);

        previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        previous.setOnClickListener(this);

        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageView); //Change accordingly
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r1); //Set your first image to be displayed
        a = 1; //declare a variable and set it to 1

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.swipepage, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.next:
                if (a == 1) {
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r2);
                    a = 2;
                } else if (a == 2) {
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r3);
                    a = 3;
                } else if (a == 3) {
                    Toast.makeText(ImageScreen.this, "No more photos to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;
break;

            case R.id.previous:
                if (a == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(ImageScreen.this, "No more photos to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;
                } else if (a == 2) {
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r1);
                    a = 1;
                } else if (a == 3) {
                     image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r2);
                    a = 2;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi gilonm, see what I posted above.

Comment: Hi! Check my edited answer.  You will see I declared you Buttons, ImageView and int a ABOVE the onCreate method, and in you switch statment I added a "break" after the first case. Try it now...

Answer (score 0):

I tried what the last user posted, but on this part of the code, the "a" and the "image" parts are red and says it cannot resolve symbol.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.next:
            if (a == 1) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r2);
                a = 2;
            } else if (a == 2) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r3);
                a = 3;
            } else if (a == 3) {
                Toast.makeText(swipepage.this, "No more photos to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                case R.id.previous:
                    if (a == 1) {
                        Toast.makeText(swipepage.this, "No more photos to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;
                    } else if (a == 2) {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r1);
                        a = 1;
                    } else if (a == 3) {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.r2);
                        a = 2;
                        break;
                    }
            }
```

}